# SimpleCursorAdapter for populating a spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I have to populate a spinner with the names of the columns of a table in my database.
Following is the code snippet for the same:

```
SQLiteDatabase data = Utils.openDatabase(this);
    Cursor dataCursor = data.query(ConstObj.TABLE_LABELS, null, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    String[] list = dataCursor.getColumnNames();
    Log.d("", "logger list=" + list.toString());

    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataCursor, list, to);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

When I execute this code, my spinner shows no items.

Also I want to make the final item of the spinner as "-Create your own label-"

Can somebody give me any inputs?

Comment: dataCursor.getColumnNames() returning how many columns..?

Comment: It is returning 4 columns

Comment: in the list mention which one you required...

Comment: int[] to
String[] list must have same array length...not diff

Comment: How should I alter the length of int[] accordingly?

Comment: Its not pssible...in list add singl column...it will works...

Answer (score 0):

i think you got empty list view because of You never declare column attribute to retrieve column in query

```
String[] column = {col1, col2, col3};
Cursor dataCursor = data.query(ConstObj.TABLE_LABELS, column //(here you add null), null, 
null,null, null, null);
```

Comment: But null specifies that all columns should be selected which is the functionality I want.

Comment: no its not like that you need to select columns null mean there is nothing in this attribute

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/4550896/return-all-columns-of-a-sqlite-table-in-android

Comment: whats that i can't pickup this link